# Create file paths based on variable content

Tags: r

I would like to save different data frames in R that is titled with a year. My approach so far has been to do like this:

```
year <- 2020
write.table(df, file = "D:/.../.../df_year.xlsx")
```

If I am using the above approach, I am ending with a data frame called df_year.xlsx, but I want it to be named "df_2020.xlsx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the glue package (Part of the tidyverse) for this:

```
library(stringr)
year <- 2020
write.table(df, file = str_glue("D:/.../.../df_{year}.xlsx"))
```

Alternatively, one can use `paste`:

```
write.table(df, file = paste0("D:/.../.../df_", year, ".xlsx"))
```

Comment: @JosL I revised my answer